# Most Appropriate Method for Getting Data from Multiple View controllers?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm not sure how to go about retrieving data from several views.

Say I have a base view which can access other views (like a menu with a save button on the top right).

In order for the user to click "Save" and store that information into a database, they must complete the forms that are accessible from the base view (similar to Ebay's Seller Listing where the seller has to fill out information about Condition, Details, Format & Price, etc. that are placed in seperate VCs).

I know about delegates which can be used to pass data back to the base view/prepareForSegue method. Does the data that is passed back from say, form A, stay in the base view controller when the user goes to form b and passes the data back to the base view controller?

Also, I've read that a view controller can access another view controller's variables (in my case, the base view controller would try to see if all the variables/form data are set).

Any suggestions how I would go and approach this?

Example of what I'm trying to replicate:

Core menu: https://scontent-sjc2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtf1/v/wl/t34.0-12/12784465_1064321083612978_180763870_n.jpg?oh=611c44a4337e06fff226d4ee0ae66619&oe=56D07FBD

Submenu form: https://scontent-sjc2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/wl/t34.0-12/12767404_1064321136946306_596763876_n.jpg?oh=269a1b538fca75f3cabb28dc6b50058e&oe=56D0C0D7

Answer (score 0):

You can store data with `NSUserDefaults`, `CoreData`, `sharedApplication Delegate` and other methods. What you should use depends on your needs.

But I think you should start with some basic tutorials on how to develop for iOS. Your question shows that you don't really understand the topic and this site is for specific programming questions and problems.

I hope this helps anyways.

Comment: The thing is that I don't really want to store settings/data permanently in the user's device. It is supposed to be stored temporarily until the user finalizes and hits the "submit/save" button which then stores it to my database.

If you have the Ebay app, check out the selling page where the seller has to set the attributes for the thing they are about to list and sell.

Comment: Then you can use the SharedApplication Delegate. There you can store global Data in your Application and it wont Save on the device.

Comment: I just went with the singleton pattern. It works, but I'm not sure if it's a better alt compared to the SharedApplication delegate.

Comment: Like i said, there are many ways to transfer or store data.Your question is to broad to be answered correctly.